# Multiple instances of react-quill instances in react form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, validation, react-quill

I need to add multiple instances of ReactQuill in single react form. Also, perform required field validation on it and store that individual value. Can anyone help me?

I have created codesandbox link : https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-waterfall-xp1t1

Answer (score 0):

Just add different onchange event handlers for the four editors since Quill shares the value attributes as oppossed to other input tags.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).